# Is it possible to embed a package without to copy it?

Tags: google-app-engine, go

Say there we have the package encoding/json. Can I just create a package mypackage and embed all the functions (at least the public functions) into my package without to copy them by hand and basically do calls back to the actual json package? I'm developing a cross platform (Google app engine / native ) solution and I would find a such solution quite useful.

Comment: What do you mean by "embedding"? If you're calling functions in another package. it doesn't matter how many layers you hide it behind, you still need to install that package.

Comment: Please explain what you mean. What you've said makes no sense ... particularly the "copy them by hand" ..

Comment: Note that just writing `import encoding/json` does not stop you from developing on GAE or cross-compiling. Since it's also part of the standard library, there's no need to 'vendor' it because it adheres to the Go1 compatibility promise.

Comment: I'm developing an application on Google App Engine platform. However I would like to make it work on non-appengine environments too so I have to wrap the GAE specific packages into my packages(write functions with the same name) and use build tags to build either the GAE or non-GAE version. After I put a bit more though in this I think what I actually need is basically a package alias not embedding. Basically when a function is calling mypackage.aFunction it should call appengine.aFunction

Comment: Why not just `import myPackage "path/to/another/package"`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.

It sounds like you want some sort of package inheritance, this is not a supported feature.